# how Spring boot explicitly not load a class if it's not a web project?

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3

An independent common project A which supply common configuration, inside it there is a class

```
@RestController
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {
    @Autowired
    private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;
    //...
}
```

Now there is another project B which depend on above project A, but this is not a web project only execute some business logic then exit. So in application.properties I have this configuration:

```
spring.main.web_environment=false
```

but when run project B, it failed because this exception:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

So how to solve this problem? Could exclude `CustomErrorController` in B's pom.xml or if it's not a web project could not load `CustomErrorController`?

Answer (score 0):

`spring.main.web_environment=false` disable the embedded container even if it is present in your project. It does not perform black magic to prevent your classes to be instantiated.

If you are using component scan and you provide classes that require a web environment it will fail (as you just saw). Maybe you need to refactor your project in several modules and isolate the web part in a separate project?

Comment: Thanks! why @SpringBootApplication(exclude = CustomErrorController.class) could not help?

Comment: exclude is excluding auto-configuration, not classes (check the doc). You should probably have a `@ComponentScan` directive on your own instead of relying on the default.

Comment: Thanks! Spring boot reference says " you can explicitly call SpringApplication.setWebEnvironment(false), " but you can't do this. I think it shoud be `new SpringApplication().setWebEnvironment(false);`

Comment: good catch, [fixed](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/1ec40ed666b1287d0570ea7fe9de471508e29834)

Answer (score 0):

exclude `CustomErrorController` class

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.foo",
excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(value = ProjectAApplication.class,type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE),
                  @ComponentScan.Filter(value = CustomErrorController.class, type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE)})
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjectBApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
```